# uploading form that has files through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a form that contains both text and files. The JS is returning the success message, but the file isn't being uploaded and the entry isn't being made into the DB.

form:

```
<form class="post-form" action="javascript:void(0)" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="25" />
    <input name="title" type="text" maxlength="160" placeholder="Title..." required />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('submit', ".post-form", function(uploadVideo) {
uploadVideo.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData((this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: formData,
    success: function () {
        alert("that sh*t worked!");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("didn't work");
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: you cannot upload files using ajax...

Comment: you can try this..http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/

Comment: @SoftwareNerd Yes, you can upload files via ajax.

Comment: It seems syntax issue, 
var formData = new FormData((this)[0]); 
It should be 
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);